# How to Close previous same WPF when it launch again?

Tags: c#, wpf

A WPF window app opens from different window when it is running. 
But I want to close open a single window. If the app already running and I click again to the app to open again, then previous app will be closed and new app will be started..

I can close current window when the same window already running.

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

But I want to close previous window which is running.

Comment: I mean, if a app running and i reopen it, then previous window will be closed and new one will be activated.. Like a video player.

Comment: Actually what usually is done that the new one passes command parameters to the already running app, and then closes. So it is really the new one that closes and not the old one.

Answer (score 0):

To signal across process boundaries you need a OS level primitive like a named mutex.

In your application start up you should SignalAndWait on the same mutex.

Use the signal to kill an existing running process and to Signal the start of a new process.

Comment: Then start reading. All the keywords are in. This is not WPF specific btw. - not at all (except obviously that you never learned what WPF is, what processes are etc.).

Comment: The following will help with some of the basics.  Happy Coding. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsds36f0(v=vs.110).aspx